# Looker issue when trying to query the data in explore

Tags: syntax, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, looker

Rookie to looker and have been noticing the below error message

> quoteThe Snowflake database encountered an error while running this query.
> SQL Syntax Error: SQL compilation error: syntax error line XX at position YYY unexpected 'ILIKE'>quote

When analyzing the SQL generate it seems to have  generated a SQL as below :

`where Order.Country. ILIKE '%US%'` ( So not sure why this additional dot is getting included in the SQL generated)  at explore level

Our looker is a cloud version and our database in on snowflake. So could you please advise as to what might be causing this issue ?

Comment: Can you please share the LookML code for the dimension?

Comment: Check the attribute name (country dimension name).